# Copying the translation file from my template to the plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to copy two files `(rate-my-post-fa_IR.po and rate-my-post-fa_IR.mo)` in the Rate my post plugin from the template I designed.

I couldn't find the code to copy the file from the WordPress theme to the plugin but the code below does something similar to what I want to do.

This code copies a file from the plugin to the template, and I want to do the exact opposite:

```
function file_replace() {

    $plugin_dir = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'library/front-page.php';
    $theme_dir = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/front-page.php';

    if (!copy($plugin_dir, $theme_dir)) {
        echo "failed to copy $plugin_dir to $theme_dir...\n";
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'file_replace' );
```

**Source:**

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_activation_hook/

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/after_setup_theme/

---

**Edit:**

This code keeps showing me two errors:

**1)** `Error message: copy(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory`

**2)** It shows me the following path to copy the file:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\site\wp-content\themes\mytheme/languages/rate-my-post-fa_IR.mo
```

It shows me the following path to paste the copied file:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\site/wp-content/themes/mytheme/rate-my-post/languages
```

As you can see, to copy and paste the file, it only enters the **/themes/** path and does not enter the **/plugins/** path at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to check which message pops up for you:

```
function file_replace() {

    $plugin_dir = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'library/front-page.php';
    $theme_dir = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/front-page.php';

    if (!copy($plugin_dir, $theme_dir)) {
        $errors= error_get_last();
        echo "COPY ERROR: ".$errors['type'] . "<br />\n";
        echo "Error message: ".$errors['message'] . "<br />\n";
        echo "failed to copy $plugin_dir to $theme_dir...\n";
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'file_replace' );
```

You will see that it can happen to show that it is a write permission error on the folder. So a little [PHP CHMOD](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) might help.

Comment: I keep getting this error:

`Error message: copy(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory`

Comment: Also I get two identical routes in my template: **1)** The path from which I want to copy the file:
  `C:\xampp\htdocs\site\wp-content\themes\mytheme/languages/rate-my-post-fa_IR.mo` . **2)** The path where I want to put the copied file:
  `C:\xampp\htdocs\site/wp-content/themes/mytheme/rate-my-post/languages`

Comment: Both paths go into **/themes/** which is wrong. A path must be entered in **/plugins/**.

Comment: Based on your last test, I made a modification and posted it here. Because __FILE__ will take the path in relation to the file it is reading. Putting a constant can solve. Please try again.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put a constant in your plugin.

```
<?php
define( 'CNST_MY_PLUGIN', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
```

Now in your function, set it to (note that I changed the order of the if parameters of the copy):

```
<?php
function file_replace() {
     $plugin_dir = CNST_MY_PLUGIN . 'library/front-page.php';
     $theme_dir = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/front-page.php';

     if (!copy($theme_dir, $plugin_dir)) {
         $errors= error_get_last();
         echo "COPY ERROR: ".$errors['type'] . "<br />\n";
         echo "Error message: ".$errors['message'] . "<br />\n";
         echo "failed to copy of theme $theme_dir to plugin directory $plugin_dir\n";
     }
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'file_replace' );
```

Comment: I copied the **constant** into my plugin and theme and got a **fatal** **error**. But by copying it to the **functions.php** file, the fatal error did not occur, but the previous errors remained.

Comment: What fatal error is displayed?

Comment: I copied the constant in my theme's **index.php** file and also in the plugin and this error was displayed: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "CNST_MY_PLUGIN" in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\wp-content\themes\mytheme \functions.php:528`

Comment: This constant should only be in your plugin. Is he active? Are you putting this constant in the first few lines of your source code?

Comment: The plugin is unavailable to me. I want to create a translation file for several plugins in my template and make it available to users. And if a user installs my recommended plugin from WordPress, my translation files will be automatically copied to the plugin path. I can't ask the user to copy this **constant** into the desired plugin to have the plugin translated for them. Is there an easier way to do this automatically?

Comment: Now your intention is clearer. He had initially thought it was just his plugin. So in this case there should be a more complex routine and I don't know this format at the moment. Hope you find the solution. If I find something, I'll post it here.